# CSS style overriding using jQuery not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to fix the position of my share icons on windows scroll. so i set the position fixed on scroll event. Its not working properly.

1. position fixed important is not working.
2. If i scroll up at the starting point(at the place where scroll stops) the default is not replicated.
   **CSS edited**
   js:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function () {
   var shareLink = $('#article_tools');

     function setHeader(){
      if($(window).width() <= 990){
       var shareLink = $('#article_tools');
       if( shareLink.length > 0) {
           shareLink.prepend($(".social-share-custom"));
           shareLink.next().css({'margin-top': shareLink.outerHeight(true) + "px", 'float': 'left'});
       }
       else{
           var social_alone = $(".social-share-custom");
           $(".evt_detail_main").before(social_alone);
           social_alone.next().css('float', 'left');
       }

       $(".author-article-info, .orange_oval, .author-article-organization").wrapAll('<div class="author-details"></div>');
   }
   if ($(window).width()<768) {
       shareLink.prepend($(".social-share-custom"));
       $('.follow-login-wrapper').append($('#top-login'));
       $('.responsive-menu').append($("#simplemenu"));
       $('#logo-title').after($('#container-search'));
       $('#homemenu').after($('#primary').find('>ul>li'));
       $('#comments').before($('#sidebar-right').find('#sidebar-right-inner>#block-constant_contact-0'));
   }
   ```

   }

   $( window ).resize(function() {
       setHeader();
      });

   ```
   $(window).scroll(function(){
   if($(window).width()<=990) {
       if (shareLink.length > 0) {
           shareLink.next().css('margin-top', shareLink.outerHeight(true) + "px");
           shareLink.css("top", Math.max(0, 274 - $(this).scrollTop()));
           shareLink.css('background-color', 'white');
       }
       else{
           var social_alone = $(".social-share-custom");
           social_alone.next().css('margin-top', shareLink.outerHeight(true) + "px");
           social_alone.css("top", Math.max(0, 200 - $(this).scrollTop()));
           if(social_alone.css("top") == "0"){
               social_alone.attr('style','position: fixed !important');
           }
           social_alone.css({'background-color':'white','width':'64%'});
       }
   }
   ```

   });

   setHeader();
   });

css:

```
     .social-share-custom {
     float: left;
     width: auto;
     position: static !important;
     margin: 1%
    }
```

some one do this trick.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$(".social-share-custom").css({"position":"fixed !important"});
```

Instead of:

```
 social_alone.attr('style','position: fixed !important');
```

Comment: i am having important in css position static .. And i am getting only position:fixed not fixed !important in my browser.

Comment: @Sami clear your cache memory for the browser then refresh using (ctrl + f5)

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
social_alone.attr('style','position: fixed !important');
```

with

```
social_alone.css({ position: fixed!important });
```

Also try to leave the !important out first, if it works without then you don't need it :)